# How to Set a GitHub Retention Policy for Individual Users in an Organization-wide Limit?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I'm currently facing a challenge regarding artifact storage in our github organization. At present, we have set a limit of 5 days as the retention policy for the entire organization. The reason behind this decision was that some members were retaining artifacts for an unnecessarily long period, consuming the free space available in our team plan.

However, one of our team members, has a genuine use case where he needs to store a 0.5 MiB file for more than the stipulated 5 days in one repository. The issue is that he can't adjust his individual retention policy beyond the organization's set maximum of 5 days.

How can I resolve this discrepancy and allow the guy to extend his retention policy without affecting the overall organizational limit? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

1. I tried to set the org. limit to a higher one and use repository templates with default value set lower that the org. limit and then create a new repository from that template. The value wasn't set to the one from the template, it uses the org. limit instead.
2. I tried to set the limits using github REST API, but such a feature isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not provide a built-in feature to set individual retention policies for users within an organization-wide limit directly within the platform itself. GitHub primarily focuses on version control and collaborative development rather than comprehensive data retention policies. However, you can implement certain practices to achieve similar results, considering the existing features and third-party tools available. Please note that GitHub's features and capabilities may have evolved since then, so I recommend checking GitHub's official documentation or contacting their support for the latest information.

Comment: ChatGPT generated response, which solves nothing.